# Why does Rails add semi-colon at the end of Javascript files and how to disable it?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Rails seems to add ; at the end of files ending with .js

How to disable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the file extension to .json worked for me as I was expecting a JSON file in AJAX request.

Answer (score 2):

It did so when I forgot to close all parentheses in my Javascript file properly. Check your script if all parentheses have a match.

Answer (score 0):

By default Sprockets will append a semi-colon. You can disable it by add following code to `config/initializers/assets.rb`

`Rails.application.config.assets.configure do |env|
   env.unregister_postprocessor 'application/javascript', Sprockets::SafetyColons
end`